# Looking for an example of a local base in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I've started reading Functional Analysis by Rudin and I'm trying to understand local bases.

He says that, in a vector space context, local base will always mean a local base at $0$, and that a local base of a topological vector space $X$ is a collection $\beta$ of neighbourhoods of $0$ s.t. every neighbourhood of $0$ contains a member of $\beta$.

I'm trying to understand what this would mean when $X = \mathbb{R^2}$, for example. It seems that there is no such collection $\beta$ as if we consider an element $B$ of $\beta$, where $B$ is a neighbourhood of $0$, well no matter how small we take $B$ to be we could just choose an even smaller neighbourhood of $0$ and then this smaller neighbourhood wouldn't contain $B$ and hence as $B$ is arbitrary, this implies $\beta = \emptyset$.

What am I not understanding here? Can someone give me an explanation of a local base of $\mathbb{R^2}$ that might help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of local base of $\Bbb{R}^2$ is
$$\beta = \{ B(0,r) : r >0\}$$
where $B(0,r)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$. Another is
$$\beta' = \left\{ B\left( 0,\frac{1}{n} \right) : n \in \Bbb{N} \right\}$$
which is countable. As a matter of fact, one says that $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a countable based space.

As you can see, every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ contains a small ball centered at $0$ (by definition of neighbourhood). No matter how small you can $U$, you will always find some $B \in \beta$ such that $B \subset U$.

Comment: Very nice, makes sense now!